# Windows 10: run cmd at power-on WITH console window

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, console, task-scheduler

I have a batch file (which sets some stuff up and runs a Python script) that must be run at Windows 10 power-on; not log-on, power-on.  The Python script outputs useful diagnostics to the console and so the simplest thing I could do to see these diagnostics would be to have the console window visible so that, if I subsequently log-in to the Windows 10 machine, I can see what's been going on in the recent past.

Is there any way of doing this?  I've tried Task Scheduler but as soon as one selects "Run whether user is logged on or not" the console no longer appears.  I realise that I could log the output to a file but then I would need to find some way of tailing the log, or I could wrap it up in an app, etc., but this is all extra complication when having the console window visible is really all I need.

Comment: I have a batch file (which sets some stuff up and runs a Python script) that must be run at Windows 10 power-on;    <-- It must run as a service in order to run before login.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap up a cmd as a service such that it has a visible console?

Comment: You should be able to do this.   https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: Thanks! Looks like `SrvStart`, and likely the other utilities of this type, aren't recommended for batch files as they can't clean-up sub-processes. But anyway, I've got the idea, somehow make what I want to do into a service.